# Integrating a B-Spline basis function with respect to the standard normal PDF

Tags: numerical-methods, gaussian-integral, spline, hermite-polynomials, quadrature

I am looking for ways to evaluate *exactly* (i.e. *analytically* or *semi-analytically*) integrals of the type:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}B_{i}^k(u)e^{-\frac{(u-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}du,
$$
where $B_i^k$ is a spline of order $k$, an element of the B-Spline basis for the linear space of splines of order $k$ on knots $\{t_i\}$, defined as usual recursively by:
$$
B_i^k(x)=\frac{x-t_i}{t_{i+k}-t_i}B_i^{k-1}(x)+\frac{t_{i+k+1}-x}{t_{i+k+1}-t_{i+1}}B_{i+1}^{k-1}(x),
$$
with
$$
B_i^0(x)=\begin{cases} 
      1 & x\in [t_i;t_{i+1}) \\
      0 & \text{otherwise  }
   \end{cases}
$$
Of particular interest would be the case of $\mu=0, \sigma=1$.

I am aware of the [Gauss-Hermite quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Hermite_quadrature) :
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\approx \sum_{i=1}^n w_i f(x_i),
$$
where $x_i$ are the roots of a Hermite polynomial of order $n$ and $w_i$ are the associated weights. ***Importantly, the approximation sign can be replaced by an exact equality when $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq 2n-1$***. (There are versions where the integral is with respect to $e^{-x^2}$ instead of $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$, by changing the type of Hermite polynomial employed).

My question is : is there such an **exact** equality formula for B-spline basis functions?
I am looking to express the integral at the beginning of this question as a sum analogously to the Gauss-Hermite quadrature.

**EDIT:** The problem seems to be that even though $B_i^k$ is known to have finite support, it is not itself a polynomial: each of the restrictions $B_i^k|_{(t_j;t_{j+1})}$ is a polynomial, without the full function being a polynomial. Otherwise, the answer would have been a trivial application of the Gauss-Hermite quadrature. Is is possible that there is a Gauss-Hermite-type quadrature for integration domains that are compact intervals (as opposed to integration domains that are $\mathbb{R}$) ?